# SP 2010 Alternative to Term Store Metadata?

Tags: 2010, 2016, managed-metadata, term-store

I am working on a site in SP 2010 that has some functionality that requires the use of metadata tagging for several different list items. It was proposed to the client that this would be the best method for tagging items as opposed to creating separate choice columns since it was more easily managed. Unfortunately their IT department has expressed concerns with being able to migrate the term store metadata when they upgrade to SP 2016/Cloud.

I have done some initial research and haven't found anything that presents an issue with migration for the term store to 2016 but they are looking for an alternative if there are issues. So my question is, are there any other alternatives to managing metadata in the term store that are functionally the same or similar that I could use instead? Also, if anyone could provide more information on why there may be issues with migrating a term store to 2016 that would be helpful also.

Answer (score 1):

Migrating the Term Store isn't really a migration but rather a Copy. You must first close all Term Sets in a particular Term Group on-prem then you can copy the Term Group to SPO. All information is retained, including IDs. Any items added to the Term Sets in the Term Group in SharePoint Online (where the Term Sets can be in an open state) will copy back down to SharePoint 2016. This is a super simple process.

[Configure hybrid SharePoint taxonomy and hybrid content types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hybrid/configure-hybrid-sharepoint-taxonomy-and-hybrid-content-types)